# Buttons text gets cleared when i press it

Tags: android, button, sdk

I am currently making an app where i have a list for request to needs to be marked as finished and another list for the items inside the request. If I select a request, the items inside it will show in the items list and buttons with actions to perform for that items. But when I choose another request and press a button, the text on the button gets cleared. I am using sdk 26 on the project. It seems that the text is not displayed but the text value is still there after I tried to see if the text value of the button is still there.

EDIT:
This is the part where I initialize the views.

```
btnCustomerInfo = findViewById(R.id.btnCustomerInfo);
btnRemoveDiscount = findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveDiscount);
btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
btnPay = findViewById(R.id.btnPay);
btnPrintBill = findViewById(R.id.btnPrintBill);
btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
```

EDIT:
This is the relevant xml code.

```
<TableRow
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnCustomerInfo"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Customer Info" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnRemoveDiscount"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Remove Discount" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnClear"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Clear" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnPay"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Pay" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnPrintBill"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Print Bill" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnTransfer"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Transfer" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnMerge"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Merge" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
      style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Update" />
</TableRow>
```

EDIT: This is my AppTheme.Button

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorAccent">#ebebea</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

I am not setting any value of button in the onClick

EDIT: Button onClicks

```
btnCustomerInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "btnTxt: "+((Button) view).getText());
                showCustomerInfoDlg(ip);
            }
        });

btnRemoveDiscount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MaterialDialog.Builder mDlgBuild = new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx);
            mDlgBuild.title("Discount");
            mDlgBuild.content("Remove discount on " + acOr.getTableName() + " " + acOr.getTableNum() + "(" + acOr.getSessionBundle() + ")" + "?");
            mDlgBuild.cancelable(false);
            mDlgBuild.positiveText("Ok");
            mDlgBuild.negativeText("Cancel");
            mDlgBuild.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Progress_dialog("Removing discount ...");
                    progressDlg.show();
                }
            });
            mDlgBuild.onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            mDlgBuild.show();
                }
            });
```

for btnTransfer:

```
final MaterialDialog mDlg = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .customView(R.layout.dlg_transfer_table,true)
                    .cancelable(false)
                    .negativeText("Cancel")
                    .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();

            TextView lblTableNum = (TextView)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.lblDlgTransferTableNumber);
            TextView lblCustomerName = (TextView)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.lblDlgTransferCustomerName);
            RecyclerView lstTable = (RecyclerView)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.lstDlgTransferTableList);
```

The other buttons do printing, opens a webview, remove items on the list for the items inside the request, and shows another button. Even if the buttons still doesn't have code in it, clicking it still removes the text on the buttons display.

EDIT: Gif

[image]

EDIT: this are the code of the two buttons

Pay button:

```
final MaterialDialog mDlg = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .title("Payment Options")
                    .customView(R.layout.dlg_pay_option,true)
                    .cancelable(false).show();

            Button btnCash = (Button)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgPayOptionCash);
            Button btnCard = (Button)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgPayOptionCard);
            Button btnOther = (Button)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgPayOptionOther);
            Button btnCancel = (Button)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgPayOptionCancel);
            Button btnRemovePayment = (Button)mDlg.findViewById(R.id.btnDlgPayOptionRemovePayment);

            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDlg.dismiss();
                }
            });

            btnCash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDlg.dismiss();
                    typeOfPayment = "cash";
                    CashPayment();
                }
            });

            btnCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDlg.dismiss();
                    typeOfPayment = "card";
                    CardPayment();
                }
            });

            btnOther.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDlg.dismiss();
                    typeOfPayment = "other";
                    OtherPayment();
                }
            });
```

Update button:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateOrder.class);
            i.putExtra("or_id", acOr.getSessionBundle());
            i.putExtra("cust_name", acOr.getCustomerName());
            i.putExtra("table_num", acOr.getTableNum());
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

At first, I already selected an item on the right then clicked pay. Next, I selected another item on the right and clicked pay. Then I clicked cancel on the dialog. Lastly, I clicked the update button.

Comment: can you please provide some of the code from onCreate or when you are working ?

Comment: show your `onClick()` and `@style/AppTheme.Button` code

Comment: You have to show more code , this much information is not enough to help you.

Comment: please show `onClick` code as @jignesh told u

Comment: sorry, i am taking that English is not your first language, but from what i understand is that when you click a button, the text in that button disappears? Am i correct?

Another thing, the code you showing us in the question is not enough for us to help you? We will need to see what happens when the button is clicked?

Comment: @x10sion yes, I am not a native English speaker. I know I wasn't able to create better sentences. I didn't post the code of the onClicks because most of it are showing MaterialDialogs which I think wouldn't give any clue to the answer I need.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the app in the problem state so that it is better to understand the problem that you are facing? A GIF will be even better.

Comment: Can you post the codes of the buttons that you used on gif? And can you say exactly the steps that you did on the gif? (press this button, then press out, then it disappears, etc)

Comment: They are few possible problems found. 1.Have you programmatically set the text pay and update Button if yes make sure you didn't set empty text? 2. Maybe in button onClick app theme will override the existing button theme. Have you added any custom attributes which related to click events to your app theme?

Comment: does the issue exists still ??

Comment: Have you tried removing the style from the buttons? I don't mean this as a fix necessarily, but if it works after that it might help you get closer to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the text is not cleared but has the background color in a certain state. To deal with it, you can create a [color state list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and set it in the `android:textColor` attribute.